# XMPP JavaXF client

Tags: java, javafx, smack

I am trying to make simple XMPP (Jabber) client in JavaFX (as a school project) using Smack API. I have already suceeded in making main window which keeps track of asociated clients (Roster list), but I am having problem with sending/receiving messages. I want to implement ordinary IM client functions - I need to track all incomming/outgoing chats and manage chat windows. What is the best way of doing so? My best guess is to store chats in some kind of array and keep track of opened chat windows (in array as well).

I have class managing connection (login), class for main window, which displays Roster...I really dont know how (and where) to implement Listener for new messages to store chat history somehow and to manage opened chat windows.

Desired function: Incomming chat -> is chat window (with this client) opened? if yes, append message to history and view in TextArray of that chat window, if no, open new window and display the message. Outgoing chat -> send the message and append to chat history (and view in according chat window). My code so far is really messy (If you are brave enough, you can download it from here: [link](http://www.kosna.cz/src.zip))

Thanks very much for your help